# Django Python : adding custom permissions to specific users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-permissions

Models.py

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("can_add_data","can add a new data"),
        )
```

This is the custom permission I've created in Models.py and I've also created these users.

[Users in Django Admin ie., http://localhost:8000/admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1aRz.png)

How do I give permission to specific users so that I can use `@permission_required('myapp.can_add_data')`  in views.py
and also where do I write the snippet? (in which file)

I'm a beginner at this so if there are any mistakes please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign permission to user through either  `Django Admin` or `Django shell`
**through django-shell**
open your django shell by `python manage.py shell` and run the following statements

```
In [1] from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission,User
In [2] permission = Permission.objects.get(name='can add a new data')
In [3] user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
In [4] user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

**through django-admin**
open your `django-admin` page and head to `Users` section and select your desired `user`.
There you can see `User permissions` section as in below image,
[image: user permission image]
Then, find your desired permission  (**ref-1**) (in your case `app_name|model_name|can add a new data`) and click (**ref-2** and **ref-3**), then save
**NOTE**: Permission assigning process is a one-time thing, so you dont have to update it every time unless you need to change/re-assign the permissions.
**How to use this permission in API**
in you `views.py`, define a view like this,

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required


@permission_required('app_name.can_add_data')
def my_view(request):
    # do something
    return HttpResponse("response")
```

Comment: did you migrated after adding `permissions` to model's `Meta` class ?

Comment: If you did it properly, must be in `Permission`. It can be fetched/see either by `ORM` or `django-admin`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but I'm blank right now. so can you please tell me what exactly to do?

I came to know that we can execute in the shell just now. so I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: I think you didn't migrated properly. So run, `python manage.py makemigrations app_name` and then run `python manage.py migrate app_name`

Comment: I did and the problem still persists.

this is my models.py http://prntscr.com/ikbvez

Comment: It's an internship project so I'm afraid I can't. but I think I can show you on TeamViewer or any software

Comment: hey!!
I ran this 

`python manage.py migrate app_name zero`

and then migrated the app then it worked.

thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)